# EE8 JCache annotation CacheResult doesn't work

Tags: java, ehcache, jcache, java-ee-8

I'm developing a WEB APP under JBoss EAP 7.2 (EE8) using EhCache as JCache implementation (JSR 107)

I have this code:

```
@Inject
CacheManager cacheManager;

@CacheResult(cacheName = "roles")
public List<RoleDTO> get(@CacheKey String id) {
    return service.getRoles(id);
}

public List<RoleDTO> getRoles(final String userId) {

    final List<RoleDTO> output = get(userId);

    return output;
}
```

According to this [article](https://www.tomitribe.com/blog/using-jcache-with-cdi/) I read, I'd expect the second time I access the get(userId) method should use cache and ignore entering the method, but is not so.
I also queries injected cacheManager, and "roles" cache is always empty.

Where am I wrong ?

**EDIT**

I guess EhCache 3.x doesn't support jcache annotations in a standard EE environment, on the web I can only see other CDI implementations like ri o guice.
However, by including one of these implementations, for example:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsr107.ri</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-annotations-ri-cdi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

seems the new cache entry is put onto a new cachemanager (see the below code)

```
 Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager
```

instead of the injected and configured CacheManager I already have

**EDIT EDIT**

```
@CacheResult(cacheName = "roles", cacheResolverFactory = AppCacheResolverFactory.class, cacheKeyGenerator = CacheKeyGeneratorFactory.class)
    public List<RoleDTO> getRoles(@CacheKey final String userId) {
```

This is my *CacheResolverFactory* class

```
public class AppCacheResolverFactory implements CacheResolverFactory {


    @Inject
    CacheManager cacheManager;

    @Override
    public CacheResolver getCacheResolver(CacheMethodDetails<? extends Annotation> cacheMethodDetails) {
        return new DefaultCacheResolver(cacheManager.getCache(cacheMethodDetails.getCacheName()));
    }

    @Override
    public CacheResolver getExceptionCacheResolver(CacheMethodDetails<CacheResult> cacheMethodDetails) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now I get this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Invalid key type, expected : java.lang.String but was : org.jsr107.ri.annotations.DefaultGeneratedCacheKey
```

**EDIT EDIT EDIT**

I've created a CacheKeyGeneratorFactory and a StringCacheKey that wraps a String value:

**CacheKeyGeneratorFactory**

```
public class CacheKeyGeneratorFactory implements CacheKeyGenerator {
    @Override
    public GeneratedCacheKey generateCacheKey(CacheKeyInvocationContext<? extends Annotation> cacheKeyInvocationContext) {
        final CacheInvocationParameter[] allParameters = cacheKeyInvocationContext.getAllParameters();
        for (CacheInvocationParameter parameter : allParameters) {
            if (StringCacheKey.class.equals(parameter.getRawType())) {
                return (StringCacheKey)parameter.getValue();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**StringCacheKey**

```
public class StringCacheKey implements GeneratedCacheKey {

    private String value;

    public StringCacheKey(String param) {
        this.value = param;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.value.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj != null && obj.getClass() == this.getClass() && this.value.equals(((StringCacheKey)obj).getValue());
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then I changed ehcache.xml configuration with this:

```
 <cache alias="roles">
    <key-type>mypackage.StringCacheKey</key-type>
    <value-type>java.util.List</value-type>
```

And the method with @CacheResult too

```
public List<RoleDTO> get(@CacheKey String id)
```

Now it goes, however I wonder I can save all this bunch of code and class to make it work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RI wraps keys by default into `DefaultGeneratedCacheKey`. You need to change your EHCache configuration to allow `Object` types for the key. Alternatively you can register your own key generator and use your own key type. You can of course also specify `org.jsr107.ri.annotations.DefaultGeneratedCacheKey` in your EHCache configuration, however, then you bind to a specific implementation.

Unfortunately, the JSR107/JCache standard for annotations requires that a cache key implements the interface `GeneratedCacheKey`. That means, if you have a simple cache key like int or string, these always need to get wrapped, when stored into the cache.

Side note: There is no technical need for the interface `GeneratedCacheKey`, since it does not define any new methods. This is a known problem in the standard. Unfortunately, there was no sufficient vetting of the annotations part before the standard got finalized.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it confirms my guess. Here I found some examples of implementation, https://github.com/tomitribe/jcache-cdi/blob/master/README.adoc, btw I hope the future specs will improve this actual one

Comment: Do you think I can save any boiler code ? Look at my last edit

Comment: @FabrizioStellato: I was thinking a bit about that, too. Its not only boilerplate, it is also not resource friendly, since you don't need the wrapper in the cache/by a decorator. You could wrap/unwrap in the cache. I build something for this here: https://github.com/cache2k/cache2k/blob/master/cache2k-jcache/src/main/java/org/cache2k/jcache/provider/generic/storeByValueSimulation/TransformingCacheProxy.java Maybe its a good idea to fork the cdi implementation and at least make a pseudo standard for the wrapped primitive keys.